# Show cumulative totals in new column

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a simple flow statement where the user inputs `+ve` and `-ve` values and they are stored in a single table.

The table structure is

```
funds_T (date, type, amount)
```

when I run a select all query, it would return

```
Date        | Type         | Amount
2011-10-01    opening        26000.00
2011-11-20    payment        -2000.00
2011-10-10    receipt         6000.00
2011-10-09    expense        -8000.00
```

What I want is another column next to this which shows cumulative total, something like this.

```
Date        | Type         | Amount    | Total
2011-10-01    opening        26000.00    26000.00
2011-11-20    payment        -2000.00    24000.00
2011-10-10    receipt         6000.00    30000.00
2011-10-09    expense        -8000.00    22000.00
```

also, is there any way I can do a conditional formatting just like the way you do in Excel, if value > something (background color is red, etc)

My current query is

```
SELECT date,type,amount FROM funds_T WHERE date >= '$fromdate' AND date <= '$todate'
```

Following was the query that i user after Pentium's advise

```
mysql_query(" SET @total: =0;
SELECT date,type,comments,amount,@total := @total + amount AS total
FROM funds_T
WHERE
date BETWEEN '$frdate' AND '$todate'
ORDER BY date ASC ");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colors and formatting is possible in PHP, while the cumulative total can be done in SQL or in PHP. I would recomand calculating the total in the PHP at runtime in the for cycle.

If you still want in SQL you need to use [User defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)

It would be something like:

```
SET @total:=0;
SELECT `date`, 
       `type`, 
       `amount`, 
       @total := @total + `amount` AS `total` 
FROM   funds_t 
WHERE  `date` BETWEEN '$fromdate' AND '$todate' 
ORDER  BY `date` ASC
```

Comment: Wouldn't it only select? I think OP wanted to have a column with total in db.

Comment: hi Pentium, i am running the query and getting the following error
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ': =0; SELECT date,type,comments,amount,@total := @total + amount AS total FROM f' at line 1

Comment: @Pentium10 hi, i have placed the code above, can you kindly correct me where i am wrong

Comment: $frdate' AND '$todate' is sql value there, and does not gets value from PHP, you need to join it, check your quotes.